# JPA left/right join query

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have this structure from entities Aa, Bb, Cc:

- Aa has a list of Bb
- Bb has a list of Cc

-

```
public class Aa{
@OneToMany   
List<Bb> listBb;
}

public class Bb{
@OneToMany 
List<Bb> listCc;
}
```

I would like to create a JPA Criteria API query to pool Aa by an id of C:

```
public A getAaByCcId(long id) {...}
```

In native sql I would have try left join (twice). How do I do this using JPA?

Comment: Do you also have mappings in the other direction, so Cc has a single Bb, and Bb has a single Aa? If so, it might be easiest to query along those.

Comment: Yes I do have @ManyToOne as well, but it's lazy

Comment: Laziness doesn't matter for querying - if the mapping exists, you can use it in a query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also do it with joins in JPQL:

```
select a from Aa a
inner join a.listBb b
inner join b.listCc c
where c.id = :cId
```

Note that inner joins can be used here, since you have a restriction on `c.id = :cId`, which can only be true if B and C exist. But you could use left joins as well.

EDIT:

Using a Criteria query, it would look like the following (not tested):

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Aa> criteria = builder.createQuery(Aa.class);
Root<Aa> a = criteria.from(Aa.class);
CollectionJoin<Aa, Bb> b = a.join(Aa_.listBb);
CollectionJoin<Bb, Cc> c = b.join(Bb_.listCc);
criteria.where(builder.equal(c.get(Cc_.id), cId));
return em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```

Comment: Thanks JB, but I'm trying to do it using JPA Criteria API and not JPQL

Comment: See my edited answer. I would avoid the confusing (IMHO) criteria API unless you really have a dynamically generated query.

Comment: Thanks! works like a charm. In my previous project I built my dal using JPQL and now decided to try JPA Criteria API. I'm not sure I get your comment regarding "confusing criteria API", could you please elaborate some more?

Comment: I find the API hard to understand and master, lacking consistency, hard to use, and producing hard to read code. JPQL queries are much simpler to understand.

Comment: I tend to agree. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each entity has a reference to its parent entity, where `Cc`'s reference to a `Bb` is called `bb` and `Bb`'s reference to an `Aa` is called `aa`, then in JPQL, you can do:

```
select cc.bb.aa from Cc cc where cc.id = ?
```

The criteria version of this should be a simple translation.